# Op amplifier ad8232

Tags: operational-amplifier, ecg

Does anybody know how this op amp is working? And what the output signal is - avL, avR or avF. I don.t find similarities compared to a real ecg.[image]

**** Edit

I don.t understand how this amplifier returns this particular waveform if we connect those 3 electrodes.

Does single-lead means that it records the signal from one electrode?

[image]

Comment: Your question is meaningless as asked. What is "this op amp" and why do you compare it to a "real ecg"? Do you have a particular circuit in mind? If so, provide a link so we can all share it. This is an electrical engineering exchange, not a psychic hotline.

Comment: Going to need a little more info from you, until then we'll put your question on hold.

Comment: I've connected the module to an arduino board only using the electrodes and the output pin - the standard way presented there.

Comment: Presented **where**? Draw a schematic.

Comment: On the sparkfun website - https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ad8232-heart-rate-monitor-hookup-guide

Comment: @tairebit Fritzing wiring diagrams are generally not preferred here. Please provide an actual schematic. See this post for details: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics

Comment: I added the electrical sch. The output from the OUT pin is the diff between LA and RA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instrumentation amplifiers are used in order to amplify signals coming from particular part of body. They have differential amplifier inside. Diff. Amp.  substracts the  signals  coming from inputs therefore it is very good at eliminating noise. Then the signal is processed by filters. This is how you get the signal in the picture, basically.

Please go ahead and make some research about amplifiers.